# Как обезопасить приложение от патча?

Tags: java, android

Есть приложение которое защищено проверкой подписи, но есть патч который подменяет оригинальную подпись -> она всегда верна. Патч изменяет строку android:name в блоке `<application>`(не activity, а именно application) на кастомный путь к обработчику, который создал патч. Видимо, обработчик реагирует на метом getPackageInfo. Пробовал проверять содержимое android:name вот так: `Context.getPackageManager.getApplicationInfo().name`
В итоге я всегда получаю null(даже после патча).

Comment: В принципе, любую проверку в коде можно обойти - главное найти её код, понять как он работает, а дальше дело техники... `ApplicationInfo.name` - это что-то другое.  Попробуйте `ApplicationInfo.className` или получить имя непосредственно у самого Application-класса  `activity.getApplication().getClass().getName()` или `context.getApplicationContext().getClass().getName()`.

Comment: Попробовал вместо name поставить className и настроил вывод в тост. Сработало! Спасибо!